# Phrasing conditional situation in past

Tags: grammar, conditionals

What is the difference in these two sentences

1. If you went to bed earlier, you would not be so tired
2. If you had gone to bed earlier, you would not have been so tired

To me, both of these are talking about a condition in past, if that condition has occurred then outcome would have been different, then why the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is generally tired (looks tired every day, for instance), I would tell them:

> If you went to bed earlier, you would not be so tired

Meaning that I think they *generally* go to bed too late.

If someone complains about being tired this specific morning, I could say:

> If you had gone to bed earlier, you would not have been so tired

Meaning that they should have hit the sack earlier yesterday.

Comment: "If the weather was not so bad, we would go to the park". This one is similar to the first sentence in structure but does not seem like a pattern or general behavior. What about this?

Comment: If the weather were not so bad, we would go to the park. Or, if the weather had not been so bad, we would have gone to the park.